# Why does my Ubuntu 18.04 randomly shut down?

Tags: 18.04, shutdown

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 (start with server edition, because the hardware is pretty weak) on some older hardware - a desktop. Memtest ran fine on it before I installed, but it seems that it will randomly shut down - typically when I'm doing something like a `sudo apt-get update`. It appears to go through the normal shutdown process - I see all the shutdown messages, etc. But it's definitely a forcible sort of stop since I have to run `dpkg --configure -a` or whatever it is if I was in the middle of installing software.

Any clue what could be happening here? I have a theory it might be related to power consumption but I'm not sure why that would cause what I'm seeing. If I run glxgears I can run like 10 of them at a time (slows my FPS way down, of course) for a couple of minutes and then beeeooooop! Off my machine goes.

Is there somewhere I could look?

Comment: I had a similar problem.  It's probably a heat sensor (just spitballing, I haven't checked).  Where if I run a VM within virtualbox on a single core machine, it has no problem pegging out the processor at 100%.  So, heat most probably is the issue if it sits there pegged.  Windows probably just had more loosey-goosey heat tolerances or doesn't do heat based shutdowns.

Comment: @RobotHumans how would I be able to check that?

Comment: Can you please tell us more about the shutdown messages that you see? Also, review /var/log/syslog at the time of shutdown for helpful warnings and notifications. If you run across any, please add them to your question.

Comment: If it is truly random it is likely a hardware error. Check in /var/log/ if you can find an log that got updated and if it shows any errors.

Comment: I couldn't find anything in `/var/log/syslog` - not even anything about shutting down. I even did an `ag power` (`grep -Inri power .` equivalent) in `/var/log/` with nothing suspicious. Any other terms I should keep an eye out for?

Comment: I'ld also look at dmesg output.  If you see kernel panic anywhere, that's your problem.

Comment: There's [a program called `stress` that can stress the CPU, drives, or memory to see if stressing one causes a shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3098833/7208029).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case, it turned out to be an Nvidia driver that caused random shutdowns.  I had the driver 396.54, but removing it and installing the 390.87 fixed the problem.
You can do something like

```
sudo apt purge 'nvidia*'
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt install nvidia-390
```

Comment: Finally got around to reinstalling and this appears to be it

Answer (score 4):

For me it was also the temperature limit, although I think it is a false postive and something makes that value jump somehow. I recently changed batteries on my old Lenovo T430s and these things started happening.

This way I found out:

```
cat /var/log/kern.log | grep shutting
```

And it showed this:

```
Jan 10 11:36:34 kernel: [166814.992608] thermal thermal_zone0: critical temperature reached (128 C), shutting down
```

Comment: So how did you fix it?

Answer (score 2):

If the above doesn't work for you it might be because the current drivers might not be recommended for Ubuntu 18.04 on your machine.

First remove all current drivers

```
sudo apt purge 'nvidia*'
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
```

Try running

`ubuntu-drivers devices`

and install the driver that has recommended next to it using

`sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

then reboot